# Getting a 1326 error when launching Named Pipe server and client

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I'm very new to C++ but trying to get a named pipe working between my desktop and my laptop. Whenever I run the program I get a 1326 STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE. The code can currently work if launched off the same device, assuming I switch the client IP address. However, when I moved the client to my desktop this is now when the error occurs.

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <lmuse.h>
#include <lm.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char **arv){
    wcout << "Creating an instance of a named pipe..." << endl;

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    psd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(psd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(psd, true, NULL, false);
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = psd;

    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe"), 
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, 
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NULL
    );
    if(pipe == NULL || pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        wcout << "Failed to create outbound pipe instance.";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Waiting for a client to connect to the pipe..." << endl;
    BOOL result = ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL);

    if(!result){
        wcout << "Failed to make connection on named pipe." << endl;
        CloseHandle(pipe);
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Sending data to pipe..." << endl;

    wchar_t data[255];
    printf("What data do you want to pass?\n");
    wscanf(L"%l[^\n]%*l[^\n]", data);

    while((getchar()) != 'n');

    DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
    result = WriteFile(
        pipe,
        data,
        wcslen(data) * sizeof(wchar_t),
        &numBytesWritten, 
        NULL
    );

    if(result){
        wcout << "Number of bytes sent : " << numBytesWritten << endl;
    } else {
        wcout << "Failed to send data." << endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(pipe);
    wcout << "Done" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char ** argv){
    wcout << "Connecting to pipe..." << endl;

    HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(
        TEXT("\\\\x.x.x.x\\pipe\\my_pipe"),
        GENERIC_READ, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );
    if(pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        wcout << "Failed to connect to pipe." << endl;
        printf("\nError occured while writing to the server %d: ", GetLastError());
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Reading data from pipe..." << endl;
    wchar_t buffer[128];
    DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
    BOOL result = ReadFile(
        pipe,
        buffer,
        127 * sizeof(wchar_t),
        &numBytesRead,
        NULL
    );
    if(result){
        buffer[numBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t)] = '\n';
        wcout << "Number of bytes read: " << numBytesRead << endl;
        wcout << "Message: " << buffer << endl;
    } else {
        wcout << "Failed to read data from the pipe" << endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(pipe);
    wcout << "Done." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Have made sure file share is enabled on both devices.

Comment: You are not using `GetLastError()` correctly. You must call it *immediately* after a failed API call. Any other calls you make beforehand (even a *seemingly innocent* `wcout` call) *could* wipe out the error code before you have had a chance to retrieve it. So, change this: `if(pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){ wcout << ...; printf("... %d: ", GetLastError()); ... }` to this instead: `if(pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){ DWORD errCode = GetLastError(); wcout << ... << errCode; ... }`

Comment: Made that switch, it still outputs the same error code "1326".

Comment: you need first call `NetUseAdd` or `WNetAddConnection2` on `\\\\x.x.x.x\\IPC$` and set user credentials

Comment: And the default security descriptor only [grant read access to members of the Everyone group and the anonymous account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createnamedpipew#parameters).